# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so I execute query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table l LIMIT 10, 20;
```

which returns 20 rows from table, and there are a total 553 rows in the table

Then i immediately execute `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`

But this instead only returns the number 1, despite the fact that there are 553 rows in my table (it's supposed to return 553, am I correct?)

what did I do wrong?

Comment: your syntax are correct, any chance you have execute another set of query before getting the results of found_rows()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a syntax error, as names in SQL are not supposed to contain spaces. Try adding square brackets around `[table 1]`, if that is the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your limit, I think there it is not showing 20 rows; it is showing only 10 rows.

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CAL_FOUND_ROWS  * FROM users "; //don;t write table then table name
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

//Use these according to your requirements:

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CAL_FOUND_ROWS  * FROM users ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `found_rows`";
$rows = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows);
$total_rows = $rows['found_rows'];
```